# Authenticating with Yelp

Tags: javascript, oauth, yelp

I am trying to build an small application in that i am allowing user to register a business. to avoid creation of fake business profiles i want to make the registration(Authentication) via YELP.Is there any way out i can achieve this with yelp.I read that the Yelp API uses oAuth1.0a to authorize and identifiy the API caller not the end user that might be using the application.Any help appreciated
Regards,
Bijesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but that is not a possibility.
In order to register a business you have to do it manually, The API won't allow you to register, only to do searches (about a business or find a business).
In order to authenticate a business yelp will make an automated call to the business you are registering and tell you a code that you then will type in and authenticate a business.
There are sites that will do that for you, They either do it all manually or maybe have their own deal with yelp (I am guessing).
I think the only way you can achieve that is by contacting yelp and inquiring if they would let you do that.

Comment: I am not looking for an automated registration.Ex My user has a yelp registration he will supply his credentials to me.I want to get the profile data from yelp using these credentials.This is my exact requirement.

Comment: So if I understand, "I" register my business in your site, and in turn your site would populate the information about my business and fill up the profile on my business.

Comment: If that is the case, you cannot (unless if you contact them and get an authorization) because of the [Display Requirements](http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/display_requirements) and the [API Terms](http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/api_terms) of Use `You agree that you will not, ... to:

cache, record, pre-fetch, or otherwise store any portion of the Yelp Content, or attempt or provide a means to execute any "bulk download" operations, ...;
modify the Yelp Content, or use it to update or create your own database of business listing information;`